# Playing Video In asp.net using html video player from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video

I am Trying to play an video in asp.net

I have taken datalist to bind data 
I have binded video control like this..

```
<video controls="controls" runat="server" id="id1" width="200" height="200">
<source  src='<%#Eval("vd_video")%>' />
</video>
```

But it cant display video in video control whether there is an video in folder 
admin/video/movie.mp4 which is inserted into database
so, please is there any one who can help me to find out solution

Comment: when you hard code the video url like src="admin/video/movie.mp4" it works?

Comment: I have seen some code from internate so many people gave example to bind video like that that's why i bind and it not works properly

Comment: If path is correct then i think you are missing `type="video/mp4"`

Comment: i have also try this but it's not working

Comment: what's in `Eval("vd_video")`?

Comment: I know but what's stored in it? What do you see when you print it out?

Comment: it stores path of video file where it placed when i run mywebsite it display only blank video control it disabled play option

Comment: what do you see in `src` attribute when you click on 'view source' in browser?

Comment: it shows <source src="~/admin/Videos/oceans_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: That's the problem, you should remove `~/` from the path of the video, browser does not recognize ~ character, it's .net specific.

Comment: I have Also try Removing ~/ but it still not working

Comment: Try `Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("vd_video"))` instead of `Eval("vd_video")`

Comment: when page was loading at that time it display play button visible but after completing page load event it display play button visible false

Comment: it's Still not working.....

Comment: And what do you see in `src` attribute after you use `Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("vd_video"))`?

Comment: yes it shows Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("vd_video"))

Comment: Ok, can you use `<%Response.Write(new System.Uri(Page.Request.Url, ResolveClientUrl(Eval("vd_video"))).AbsoluteUri); %>` instead of `<%#Eval("vd_video")%>` and see what happens?

Comment: ok let me try this..

Comment: it works on local but it's not working on live server